# Lightning component with force:* dependency will reload endlessly

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-events

I had a component defining `<aura:dependency resource="markup://force:*" type="EVENT" />` using the **wildcard** to not have to thinks about what to define when.

But the the component forced to **reload the page in a loop**. It didn't stop. Only registering the specific events made that stop.

*But I still wonder why that happened?*